# converting a hash with multi-valued field / collection / nested data to an array is problematic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j (2.14), Ruby 1.93, Rails 3.2, and Cypher queries via rest.

I have a query that has one field that is a collection (a list of IDs of interactors), and that field is causing problems when I try to create an array from the data.  Is it possible to do this given the multi-value data/collection? Or do I have to take another approach?

Here is the data that is returned (see below for YAML format etc)

```
{"columns"=>["int_node_id", "object_id", "object_type", "action", "stat", "interactors", "comment_preview", "object_description"], "data"=>[[19215, 19182, "photo", "comment", 2, [19164, 19185], nil, ""], [19207, 19196, "photo", "comment", 2, [19164, 19185], nil, ""]]}
```

It seems the intereactors collection field value, [19164, 19185], is being interpreted as being separate fields instead of one field that contains multiple values.

Here is my code that works as long as I don't have a collection in the data, but bombs when I do, as well as the resulting error:

```
array_of_hashes =results["data"].map {|row| p Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] }

ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
```

It seems Ruby doesn't know what to do with the non flat data structure of this field.

When I ask for the keys, this multi-value field (interactors) is not included:

```
array_of_hashes =results["data"].map {|row| p Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row)].keys }

- - - int_node_id
    - 19215
  - - object_type
    - photo
  - - stat
    - 2
  - - comment_preview
    - 
- - - int_node_id
    - 19207
  - - object_type
    - photo
  - - stat
    - 2
  - - comment_preview
    -
```

If my question is a bit confusing, this article on how to create such a structure might help you see what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to take such a structure and put it into an array, which is the reverse of the article.. - see   http://andywenk.github.io/programming/2014/06/27/ruby-create-a-hash-from-arrays/

One thought is to simply take the interaction field and replace the brackets with quotes, and if that's not enough, convert the comments to pipes.  So this [19164, 19185] becomes "19164-19185" this, which could solve the problem here.. But I'm trying to avoid that ..

Any advice?

```
Raw data:  {"columns"=>["int_node_id", "object_id", "object_type", "action", "stat", "interactors", "comment_preview", "object_description"], "data"=>[[19215, 19182, "photo", "comment", 2, [19164, 19185], nil, ""], [19207, 19196, "photo", "comment", 2, [19164, 19185], nil, ""]]}

Source data in YAML format
columns:
- int_node_id
- object_id
- object_type
- action
- stat
- interactors
- comment_preview
- object_description
data:
- - 19215
  - 19182
  - photo
  - comment
  - 2
  - - 19164
    - 19185
  - 
  - ''
- - 19207
  - 19196
  - photo
  - comment
  - 2
  - - 19164
    - 19185
  - 
  - ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `flatten`, which combines nested arrays *of arbitrary depth* into a flat, large one. I see that you needed to do that to satisfy the format for `Hash[key, value, key, value, ...]`

However, you can pass an integer to `flatten` to specify the depth, so this does the trick:

```
results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten(1)] }
```

However I would rewrite this with `to_h` which expects pairs of values, e.g. `[[key, value], [key, value], ...].to_h`. It just so happens that `zip` already gives you this representation, so you might as well go ahead and use it directly, instead of wasting time on flattening the array:

```
results["data"].map {|row| results["columns"].zip(row).to_h }
# => [
#   {
#     "int_node_id"=>19215,
#     "object_id"=>19182,
#     "object_type"=>"photo",
#     "action"=>"comment",
#     "stat"=>2,
#     "interactors"=>[19164, 19185],
#     "comment_preview"=>nil,
#     "object_description"=>""
#   },
#   {
#     "int_node_id"=>19207,
#     "object_id"=>19196,
#     "object_type"=>"photo",
#     "action"=>"comment",
#     "stat"=>2,
#     "interactors"=>[19164, 19185],
#     "comment_preview"=>nil,
#     "object_description"=>""
#   }
# ]
```

Comment: The flatten(1) works.. but when I use the to_h method I get the following error: undefined method `to_h' for #<Array:0x007fc943f8c820>)

Comment: I'm using the array in views, so maybe it's best to use flatten(1)?

Comment: Oops. Ruby 1.93 doesn't have to_h.. that's a 2.0 thing.. I'll stick with the flatten(1) for now.. thanks!